# How Content Controls are indexed in repeating Section Content Control?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have document with two paragraph: in the first one one Plain text CC and in the second one repeating section CC with one Plain Text CC inside.

I am trying to move all the info from CC's in repeating section to appear in first paragraph CC. So far I have come to this code:

```
 Sub first_paragraph()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim xNames As String
    Dim xEntry As String

    xNames = ""

    With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("VP_pav")

        For x = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(x)
                If .Tag = "VP_pav" Then
                    xEntry = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("VP_pav").Item(x).Range.Text
                        ' "if" for removing comma before first entry
                         If xNames = "" Then
                            xNames = xEntry + xNames
                            Else
                            xNames = xEntry + ", " + xNames
                            End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next x
        End With

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("pirm_pas").Item(1).Range.Text = xNames

End Sub
```

Problem that CC generated in repeating section CC (then adding new section) seems to get random item number (I thought that first CC with tag "example" would get item number 1, second CC with the same tag get item number 2 and etc., but it seems it is not the case).

Because newly generated CC gets random item numbers, values in first paragraph CC are out of order.

Is it possible to make newly generated CC to get sequential numbers? How they get item numbers if they are not sequential? Should take some different approach?

I am adding picture to illustrate my situation:

[image]

*P.S. I'm deletting my recently posted question about correct variables order in this situation since I determined that it is (probably) not the problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code shown, nothing is telling Word to read the content controls in any kind of order. In this case, a better approach would be to loop the content controls in the Repeaing Section content control.

The following example assumes the `RepSec` has been assigned to the `Title` of the repeating section content control:

```
 Sub first_paragraph()
    Dim xNames As String, xEntry as String
    Dim ccRepSec as Word.ContentControl
    Dim cc as Word.ContentControl

    xNames = ""

    Set ccRepSec = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("RepSec").Item(1)    
    For Each cc in ccRepSec.Range.ContentControls
         If .Tag = "VP_pav" Then
              xEntry = cc.Range.Text
              If xNames = "" Then
                 xNames = xEntry & xNames
              Else
                 xNames = xEntry & ", " & xNames
              End If
         End If
    Next cc

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("pirm_pas").Item(1).Range.Text = xNames    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for advise, I think I am getting close, but with code you provided I am getting Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference on `.Tag` part. I have edited it to `If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("VP_pav").Item(1).Tag = "VP_pav" Then` , but now I encountered different problem. In my example there are only one CC per repeating section CC, in real document there are 11 of them and now they all shows in first paragraph CC box, but I only need first CC in repeating section CC value to be moved. How do I make code stop after first CC in repeating section CC?

Comment: I also find seemingly similar question  in [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/iterate-sequentially-through-the-content-controls/c4892f8a-4244-40dc-9b32-a195f792f095?db=5) but I have trouble understanding Word object management in VBA. So I cant get a grasp on use of array in given link example code: `Set docCCs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTage("summary")
x = docCCs. Count
For Each cc in docCCs
i = i + 1
Set myRange = cc.Range
arrData(i,2) = myRange.Text
arrData(i,3) = myRange.Start
Next` Can I somehow make a use of it in my situation?

Comment: To your first comment: The `If` you show makes absolutely no sense. If you select the content controls by tag there's no need to further test the `Tag` property. Also, assign to a content control object. In my test the repeating content control had multiple, nested content controls. Your example specifically requested looping all the nested content controls, so I don't understand your "new" problem. But building on *my* sample code to get the first one: `ccRepSec.Range.ContentControls(1)` will return the first.

Comment: I am absolutely baffled by MS-Word object management. I am trying to run exact same code you have provided, but getting "Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference" with `Sub first_paragraph()` marked yellow and `.Tag` marked blue. As for looping, maybe I was little bit unclear, I need to loop through all repeating section CC in which there will be several nested CC's. From each repeating section CC I need to find specific nested CC and take it value.

Comment: I finally found the problem If .Tag = "VP_pav" Then line should be If cc.Tag = "VP_pav" Then . I have spend way too long staring at the code and trying to think another solution, while whole code needed only two letters... Now everything works perfectly. Thank you.